# Generate all possible numbers with mask

Tags: python, combinations, mask

Let's say I have a string like:

```
a = "123**7*9"
```

And I need to generate all possible combination of it:

```
12300709...12399799
```

How to do that with Python?

Comment: Strings or integers as output?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could use [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) and string formatting:

```
>>> from itertools import product
>>> strs = "123**7*9"
>>> c = strs.count("*")              #count the number of "*"'s
>>> strs = strs.replace("*","{}")    #replace '*'s with '{}' for formatting
>>> for x in product("0123456789",repeat=c):
...     print strs.format(*x)               #use `int()` to get an integer

12300709
12300719
12300729
12300739
12300749
12300759
12300769
12300779
12300789
12300799
....
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also do it like this only using the standard library:

```
a = "123**7*9"
a = a.replace("*", "%d")
for x in range(10):
    for y in range(10):
        for z in range(10):
            print a % (x,y,z)
```

EDIT, BOOM:

```
a = "123**7*9"
c = a.count("*")
a = a.replace("*", "%s")
for x in range(10**c):
    print a % tuple(list("%03d" % x))
```

Comment: Assuming you have exactly `3` asterisks

Comment: I thought about such solution, but it's not so nice as the given answer:)

Comment: same thing, but now for any number of wildcards.

Answer (score 0):

Recursion variant:

```
def combinate(pattern, order=0):
    if pattern:
        for val in combinate(pattern[:-1], order+1):
            last_value = pattern[-1]
            if last_value == '*':
                for gen in xrange(10):
                    value = gen * (10**order) + val
                    yield value
            else:
                value = int(last_value)*(10**order)+val
                yield value
    else:
        yield 0


for i in combinate('1*1**2'):
    print i
```